# Curve Modifier and Texts

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

I have watched a couple of tutorials on wrapping text on a circle but I want to wrap a text on a square and came up with some strange results. I came up with the idea of using the Symbol text that was extruded to make a decorative boarder. But what happens is the symbols stretch more on the short ends of the rectangle. I tried using thew word spacing in the fonts with no success. Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do without the ends stretching or am I missing something?

What I did was select the lines going around my object and duplicated them and turned them into curve from mesh and then centered everything and then applied curve modifier and this was the result. Any Ideas? [image]

Comment: Make sure you apply the scale on both the text object and deforming curve, also make sure you curve has uniform scale and is set to *2D*. Text and curve objects are generally not very suitable for deforming directly due to their bad topology

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The 2D option took my rectangle path  object and made it into one line so did not use it.  I  was able to get it to work but not sure what I did. But then their is still the trick of getting my border objects even around the curve object.  This would be nice way to create borders for square objects. This time I also used a nice decor object  instead of text. But was also able to get the text to work but as stated need to figure out how to get the objects even around the rectangle path.